# How to check validation of value range of radNumericTextBox in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How to check validation of value range of radNumericTextBox ? 
I want to stop insert , when I enter incorrect value in radNumericTextBox.
When I enter incorrect value in radNumericTextBox , and click on btnInsert, controls change value into 0 and save.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" ValidationGroup="oppSub" DisplayMode="List" />
    <div dir="rtl">
        <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtDiscount" Type="Percent" MinValue="0" MaxValue="100"
            AllowOutOfRangeAutoCorrect="false" ShowSpinButtons="true"
            ValidationGroup="oppSub"
            runat="server">
            <NumberFormat KeepNotRoundedValue="false" DecimalDigits="3" DecimalSeparator="."
                AllowRounding="false"></NumberFormat>
        </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" Text="save" runat="server"
            ValidationGroup="oppSub"></asp:Button>
    </div>
```

Comment: share your code behind please!

Comment: I have not code in .ascx. Just , want to check validate in client side

Comment: I use this controls in user control

Comment: Samiye Mehdi manam iraniam. mishe komak koni?

Comment: vaghti ke roye btnInsert click mikonam, meghdare txtDiscount 0 mishe va to database save mishe

Comment: yes.please get me your mail

Comment: mehdi.samiey@yahoo.com

Comment: tanx. Please connect to yahoo mail